# Какого размера нужно использовать иконки для NavigationView?

Tags: android

При использовании NavigationView использую иконки xxhdpi(54x54), xhdpi(36x36), hdpi(27x27), mdpi(18x18) Но на всех устройствах они мутные. Какого размера нужно использовать иконки для неё или почему они могут быть мутные?

**UPD**

В примере Google у них размеры другие, начинается от 96x96 используя такие же по размеру, все равно мутные выходят.

Answer (score 2):

xxxhdpi(96x96), xxhdpi(72x72), xhdpi(48x48), hdpi(36x36), mdpi(24x24), ldpi(18x18) по стандартам MaterialDesign. Мутность иконки может зависеть от ряда факторов: начиная от цвета самой icon, от styles, или от состояния пункта меню(нажат, не нажат).

Comment: У них очень странные иконки используются для NavigationView, внутри пустые, после чего окрашиваются программно(так в примере).

Comment: так и есть, они серого цвета, но при нажатии становятся черными. Вы можете всё поменять, как Вам угодно.

Comment: Вот как выглядит у меня одна из стандартных иконок в ресурсах http://i.stack.imgur.com/uE9hD.png, в приложения она программно зарисовывается внутри, в зависимости от состояния. Одно из состояний: http://i.stack.imgur.com/OEnSf.png